# How can I use maps defined in avro SpecificRecordBase with flink sql table

Tags: avro, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have an avro schema with one of the fields being

```
Map<String, Object>
```

Now when I read this data from a stream and try to register it in a flink sql table

```
        final DataStream<Event> eventStream = .....(Event is the SpecificRecordBase with Map<String, Object as one of the fields)
        tableEnv.registerDataStream("inputTable", eventStream);

        final Table resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT f0 FROM inputTable");

        try (CloseableIterator<Row> it = tableEnv.executeSql("DESCRIBE inputTable").collect()) {
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Row row = it.next();
                LOG.info("The element={}", row);
            }
        }
```

Now I see the following as the type of the field `Raw<java.util.Map>`

As a result I am not able to query against his map in flink sql. How can I make this work?